# Troubles plotting SVM in Python

Tags: python, svm

I am trying to plot my SVM that I did on my testing data and am getting an error about an unhashable type: 'slice'. I have looked through this site and did a couple Google searches but can't find an answer. Below is my code:

```
x_min, x_max = X_test[:,0].min()-1, X_test[:,0].max()+1
y_min, y_max = X_test[:,1].min()-1, X_test[:,1].max()+1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
```

I am using Python 3. Appreciate the help.

Comment: share your input data please

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and do not know how to upload a file, but I am using a random 80/20 split of this data: https://www.kaggle.com/ludobenistant/hr-analytics. I have run the SVM already and graphed the confusion matrix. I am just having trouble graphing the data output. I have also substituted dummy variables using pandas and am using 'left' as the target variable. Thanks!